# iOS Today Extension: cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, xcode6, today-extension

I'm trying to use a UITableView in my Today extension. I figure, this is what most people will want to do. When I run the extension, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is called and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called, so the table view never gets displayed. Has anyone else had success with a table view in the today extension?

Comment: Double check that you spelled the method name correctly, with all parms.

Comment: Yup, it's spelled correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The tableView will always want to know the number of rows/sections it has, but will only ask for a cell if it is about to display one, generally.

A tableView won't ask for cells it can't display, particularly when **the tableView has no height**.

Make sure your ViewController and TableView both have a non-zero area frame!

> If a widget has additional content to display, you can rely on Auto
>   Layout constraints to adjust the widget’s height as appropriate. If
>   you don’t use Auto Layout, you can use the UIViewController property
>   preferredContentSize to specify the widget’s new height.

[App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1)

Comment: And make sure that numberOfRowsInSection is returning a non-zero number.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure the tableview has height, you should also make sure you are calling reloadData on the main thread.